# How to write SPARQL query to find a literal match in all objects of all classes using Jena?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, semantic-web

(1) I have [some ontology](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzvvBDneQzShOGtCdmJ0TFFoT1k) with the next structure:[image]
Each individual has a "Data Property" with name "**value_of_individual**" and **literal**.
For example, *individualA1* has *value_of_individual* with *literal* **valueA1**; *individualB2* has *value_of_individual* with *literal* **valueB2** etc.

(2) I want to create next query: **find a literal match in all objects of all classes**. If there is a coincidence - return **true**, if there is no coincidence - return **false**.

(3) I found that I need use **ASK query**. For, example:

```
QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(""
            + "ASK { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } }"
            + "", dataset);
    boolean res = queryExecution.execAsk();
    System.out.println("The result is " + res);
```

**(4) My question:**
How do I write the query described in clause 2 and combine it with the query described in clause 3?

*Edit:*
 I have input word, for example, "MyLiteral". I want to know if there are Individuals in the ClassA, ClassB, ClassC that have a literal as a "MyLiteral" in the data property.

Comment: *"find a literal match in all objects of all classes."* ??? Can you give a concrete example, please?

Comment: @AKSW, i have input word, for example, "MyLiteral". I want to know if there are Individuals in the ClassA, ClassB, ClassC that have a literal as a "MyLiteral" in the data property.  I don't know how to write such queries.

Comment: There is no proper "for all" in SPARQL. You have two opportunities: 1) use double negation, i.e. check that there is no class where there is no such individual or 2) compare the number of all classes where there is such an individual with the total number of classes. Both queries are pretty straightforward

Comment: @AKSW, can you write me this queries for my ontology in a separate answer, please????

Comment: @Tomas, `PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX test: <http://www.semanticweb.org/test-ontology#>
ASK {?s test:value_of_individual "valueC3"^^xsd:string}` ?

Comment: @StanislavKralin, It's almost what I need. But, how to specify search only in some classes? If I add one more class (for example, ClassD), then I do not need to search in it!

Comment: @Tomas, try this (with prefixes from my previous comment): `ASK {?s test:value_of_individual "valueC3"^^xsd:string . ?s a ?cls . VALUES (?cls) {(test:ClassA) (test:ClassB) (test:ClassC)} }`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, Thank you very much! This is what I need! **off topic:** If I use the class name _with the apostrophe_, for example **Class'A**. I get this error message  `org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 249.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "\'...`. You don't know how to fix it?

Comment: @Tomas, try to escape this apostrophe using `\\` or use full URIs.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, уже принял ответ:D What is the ``?

Comment: @Tomas, я отредактировал комментарий (вернее, снес и заново написал).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm still not sure if I understood your question correctly, especially because you wrote **"find a literal match in all objects of all classes"** and the **"all objects"** is confusing...)

You have to invert the result of the following query to get the answer to your original question which I simply rewrote as:

"Is there a class that doesn't contain at least one individual with `"MyLiteral"` as value of the property `:value_of_individual`?" :

```sql
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/test-ontology#> 
ASK { 
?cls a owl:Class
FILTER NOT EXISTS {
 ?s a ?cls .
 ?s :value_of_individual "MyLiteral"^^xsd:string
}
}
```

#### Update

As per [comment from @StansilavKralin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992661/how-to-write-sparql-query-to-find-a-literal-match-in-all-objects-of-all-classes/47003731?noredirect=1#comment80968269_47003731), if the question is more about to check whether there is **"any class with an individual having the given value"** the question would be exactly what @StansilavKralin wrote in his [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992661/how-to-write-sparql-query-to-find-a-literal-match-in-all-objects-of-all-classes/47003731?noredirect=1#comment80953019_46992661):

```sql
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/test-ontology#> 
ASK {
  ?s :value_of_individual "MyLiteral"^^xsd:string
}
```

#### Final solution

```sql
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX test: <http://www.semanticweb.org/test-ontology#> 
ASK {
 VALUES ?cls {test:ClassA test:ClassB test:ClassC} 
 ?s a ?cls .
 ?s test:value_of_individual "valueC3"^^xsd:string 
}
```

Comment: Possibly @Tomas means something like "find a literal match in *any* object of *any* class" (and he thinks that, "by default", searching is possible in a particular class only)...

Comment: Ehm, good point. I understood it differently, that's why I asked him for a concrete example. Unfortunately, his reply was vague as well: *"I want to know if there are Individuals in the ClassA, ClassB, ClassC that have a literal as a "MyLiteral" in the data property.*" Maybe we have to wait for clarification. If you're right, then the query would be trivial as you posted it already in the comment below the question.

Comment: Thank you for comment!!! I meant that if I add _one more class_, for example **Class D**, then in it, I do not need to search!

Comment: Does it mean you only want to search in `A`,`B` and `C`? If so, just add `VALUES ?cls {:A :B :C} ?s a ?cls .`